# Frequency Measurement on GNU Radio

Tags: frequency, gnuradio, measurement, usrp, software-defined-radio

I use an USRP on GNU Radio for AM and FM reception.

I can display the signal after demodulation thanks to QT GUI Time sink, therefore I can view the signal and know its frequency.

But I would like to measure automatically the frequency after demodulation. I want GNU Radio to give me the value of frequency signal. Is there a possibility to do that on GNU Radio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

You need to use one of the existing frequency detectors – there's a PLL one right there in the library! Other than that, many method of frequency detection are possible to do – and *all* of them can be implemented in GNU Radio, to varying degrees of ease :)

Comment: Ok thank you for your reply, I will search examples. Do you have any examples or Documents who can help me ?

Comment: the GNU Radio tutorials on https://tutorials.gnuradio.org do help get used to working with the block library!